# Do wizards or witches wear sunglasses?

Tags: harry-potter

We learn from Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, that wizards and witches buy Muggle clothing.

> "I bought this in a Muggle shop," said the old wizard stubbornly. "Muggles wear them." 
>   -Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire pg. 83

and we know they wear glasses from the description of Dumbledore.

> "His blue eyes were light, bright and sparkling behind half-moon spectacles..." 
>  -Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone pg. 8

Knowing this, my question is: Do wizards/witches wear sunglasses?

Answer (score 4):

This composite image from the the EA game [Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire](https://www.ea.com/games/harry-potter/harry-potter-goblet-of-fire) depicts the various 'chocolate frog wizard cards' associated with the band *Weird Sisters*. As you can see, the lead guitarist [Heathcote Barbary](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/heathcote-barbary/) (pictured bottom right) is clearly shown wearing sunglasses.

[image]

---

In a [side-quest for the game Hogwarts Mystery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNHhXshnzfo&t=3340s), your character plays in a band *with* the Weird Sisters. If your character is normally depicted in plain glasses, for the main event the glasses appear tinted.

[image]

Comment: Are the games considered canon?

Comment: @CuteBaby - No. They aren't even consistent internally :-)

Comment: are the Weird Sisters, just more magical version of Twisted Sister?

Comment: @Skooba I believe it's a reference to _Macbeth_ as well.

Comment: @Giuseppe I briefly thought of the Discworld novel, but as I recall *that's* a *Macbeth* reference (one of many).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Madam Hooch wears some sort of shaded goggles in the films (your canon mileage may vary) while performing her Quidditch referee duties. While they may not be sunglasses in typical sense they would provide similar protection.

[image: Madam Hooch wearing her shaded goggles]

{Still taken from *Harry Potter and Sorcerer's Stone*}

---

While also not any level of canon (I'm just using it as a secondary source to prove Hooch's goggles were tinted), LEGO also used a shaded lens in their Madam Hooch figures.

[image: Madam Hooch LEGO figure with tinted lenses]

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is not a single mention of sunglasses in the books. Additionally, there are times when the glaring sun is specifically mentioned as an issue and yet we still find no mention of sunglasses. For example, in Chapter Nineteen of *Half-Blood Prince* the sun affects Quidditch performance:

> There was little wind; the clouds were patchy; every now and then there were dazzling flashes of bright sunlight.
>
> "Tricky conditions!" McLaggen said bracingly to the team. "Coote, Peakes, you'll want to fly out of the sun, so they don't see you coming —"
>
> "I'm the Captain, McLaggen, shut up giving them instructions," said Harry angrily. "Just get up by the goal posts!"
>
> Once McLaggen had marched off, Harry turned to Coote and Peakes.
>
> "Make sure you do fly out of the sun," he told them grudgingly.

In Chapter Thirty at Dumbledore's funeral we find the following:

> Ron's face was screwed up as though the sun was blinding him.

(Though it is possible that "as though" means that the sun wasn't actually blinding him, and it might have been a cover for crying.)

In the Quidditch match in Chapter Nineteen of *Order of the Phoenix* as well the sun is mentioned as a factor that could affect performance:

> There was no wind at all and the sky was a uniform pearly white, which meant that visibility would be good without the drawback of direct sunlight in the eyes.

Likewise in Chapter Fifteen of *Prisoner of Azkaban*:

> "Okay —  no wind to speak of —  sun's a bit bright, that could impair your vision, watch out for it — ground's fairly hard, good, that'll give us a fast kickoff — "

That we still find no mention of sunglasses even in such instances may indicate that wizards would not normally use them. Of course, it is also possible that people *were* wearing sunglasses but it wasn't an important enough detail to be mentioned. However, at the very least the Quidditch players probably weren't using sunglasses, as if they had been there would be less concern for the sun.

Answer (score -1):

Here's Luna with sunglasses:

[image: Luna Lovegood holding an issue of "The Quibbler", wearing a pair of glasses with pink frames, one red lens, and one blue lens.]

Okay, not exactly a typical muggle sunglass, but this is the closest we have got..

Comment: I don't think you can call Spectrespecs sunglasses.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You can't. They're clearly intended to be a wizard version of "X-ray specs" that would be advertised in things like comic books. They looked kind of bizarre but didn't actually do anything.